# Derivative definition for root functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$$G(x) = \sqrt{x^9+\sqrt{x^3}} $$
By using definition of derivatives, find $$G'(x)$$ where $$x>0$$
I cannot seem to factorise h out after applying the definitions, i end up with having a numerator $= 0$

Comment: Define the function properly. What is the domain ?

Comment: Edited! @SahanManodya

Comment: Why don't you write your steps so that someone here might be able to find a mistake, if any, in your work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}G'(x) =&\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sqrt{(x+h)^9+(x+h)^{3/2}}-\sqrt{x^9+x^{3/2}}}{h}\\\underset{(\small\text{rationalizing})}{=}&\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{(x+h)^9+(x+h)^{3/2}-x^9-x^{3/2}}{h(\sqrt{(x+h)^9+(x+h)^{3/2}}+\sqrt{x^9+x^{3/2}})}\\=&
\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{(x+h)^9+(x+h)^{3/2}-x^9-x^{3/2}}{h(\sqrt{(x+h)^9+(x+h)^{3/2}}+\sqrt{x^9+x^{3/2}})}\end{align}$$

Let us temporarily use $k=\sqrt{(x+h)^9+(x+h)^{3/2}}+\sqrt{x^9+x^{3/2}}$ and $k\to 2\sqrt{x^9+x^{3/2}}$ as $h\to0$

$$\begin{align}G'(x) =&
\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{(x+h)^9+(x+h)^{3/2}-x^9-x^{3/2}}
{hk}\\=&\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{(x+h)^9-x^9}{hk}+\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{(x+h)^{3/2}-x^{3/2}}{hk}\end{align}$$

You can easily obtain the limit of the first term.

$$\begin{align}\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{(x+h)^9-x^9}{hk} &=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{9hx^8+36h^2x^7+\cdots h^9}{hk} \\&=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{9x^8+36hx^7+\cdots h^8}{\sqrt{(x+h)^9+(x+h)^{3/2}}+\sqrt{x^9+x^{3/2}}} \\&= \boxed{\dfrac{9x^8}{2\sqrt{x^9+x^{3/2}}}}\end{align}$$

For the second term, rationalize again to get,

$$\begin{align}\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{(x+h)^{3/2}-x^{3/2}}{hk}&=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{(x+h)^{3}-x^{3}}{hk((x+h)^{3/2}+x^{3/2})}\\&=\dfrac{3x^{2}}{4\sqrt{x^9+x^{3/2}}x^{3/2}}\\&=\boxed{\dfrac{3\sqrt x}{4\sqrt{x^9+x^{3/2}}}}\end{align}$$

So finally you have,

> $$\dfrac{18x^8+3\sqrt x}{4\sqrt{x^9+x^{3/2}}}$$

Edit: Corrected misplaced signs.

Comment: There's a typo in the first few lines, after rationalizing it should be $(x+h)^9+(x+h)^{3/2}-x^9\color{red}{-}x^{3/2}$

Comment: @Äres Thank you, corrected it :)